# RAII with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, std-function, raii

Is [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) smart in nature like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`? I guess no? I have a `std::function` which is a class member like below.

```
class MyClass {
    typedef std::function<void(void)> Func;
    Func m_func;

public:
    MyClass() {
        m_func = []() {
            std::cout << "Func called" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~MyClass() {
       m_func = nullptr; // Is this required? 
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is it mandatory to assign `nullptr` to `m_func` in the destructor? Or should I make `m_func` into a smart pointer by doing something like below? Or is it that `m_func` is smart by default and implicitly follows RAII?

```
class MyClass {
    typedef std::function<void(void)> Func;
    std::unique_ptr<Func> m_func;

public:
    MyClass() {
        m_func = std::make_unique<Func>();
        *m_func = []() {
            std::cout << "Func called" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~MyClass() {
       // auto released
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::function` is very, very smart. Follow the link you posted to the destructor section.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like I dont need to wrap it in a unique or shared pointer.

Comment: A bit strange that it is not mentioned to be smart in official documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function. Official documentation rather mentions something like this in the Notes which is a bit confusing and sounds non RAII - "Care should be taken when a std::function whose result type is a reference is initialized from a lambda expression without a trailing-return-type."

Comment: That note doesn't really have much to do with your question.  See [`std::function::~function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/~function) for the direct answer to your question: _Destroys the std::function instance. If the std::function is not empty, its target is destroyed also._

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all std classes respect rule of 3/5/0 even if joinable `std::thread` might be considered special ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` has a destructor that deletes any resources it managed, if there are any. This line:

```
   m_func = nullptr; // Is this required?
```

is never required. A class members destructors are called automatically and if not, assigning `nullptr` is never "the right" thing. If `m_func` was a pointer you would loose the pointers value and the ability to delete what it points to.

> A bit strange that it is not mentioned to be smart in official documentation at ...

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/%7Efunction) on `std::function`s destructor:

> Destroys the std::function instance. If the std::function is not empty, its target is destroyed also.

In general it is safe to assume that a class cleans up any resources it mangages in its detructor, otherwise it can be considered as broken. Cleaning up resources in destructors is not something that came new with smart pointers. Smart pointers only apply RAII wich was present in C++ always to pointers to encapsulate managment of dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: You _can_ assign a `nullptr` to a `std::function` object, which has the effect of clearing it out (it is part of the API).  Your point about not needing to do it in the destructor is still valid, though.

Comment: @Nevin thanks. I have to admit I wrote this in a hurry and wasnt sure on the `nullptr` think, I simply removed that sentence